# hibernate annotations, hql query by interfaces?

Tags: hibernate, interface, hql

The hibernate (I'm using version 3.4) documentation for hql says that it supports interfaces, and I'm having trouble getting it to work.  I have some persistent classes (not inherited from eachother, but sharing many functions) that all share an interfaces (CategorizableEntity).  I can use it with instanceof in my java code, but I cannot query for it ("from CategorizableEntity").

I have it annotated with @Entity, but hibernate will not let me map it like the others.  Is this possible? Is there a special way to map it that I can't find?

Thank you!
Joshua

Comment: Though I'd still love to be able to do this, I have solved the problem by inheriting all objects from a common object, which may be problematic later, but is a wonderfully OO solution, I'm mostly using
@Inheritance (stragey=JOINED)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to use the full name of your interface (eg: java.util.Set instead of Set)